# OpenCV - process a stream from usb camera in wince6

Tags: opencv, camera, usb, windows-ce

I need to process video from usb camera but I don't know how to keep the stream in memory. I found a code which displays it in a windows but I can't find where it stores before it displays.
Anyone can help me to solve this problem?

Comment: Lets see some code so we can help you. In order to display an image in opencv (which you said you are doing), you have to have the image stored in some sort of data-structure be it a Mat or an IplImage* or something else. You want to process that and then display. Show us some code.

Answer (score 0):

If you [check my other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3402114/176769), you'll see that the function `cvQueryFrame()` retrieves a frame from the camera and stores it in `color_frame`, which is a variable of type `IplImage*`. OpenCV uses the type `IplImage` to represent images in memory. Of course, this example shows how to use the C interface of OpenCV, so if you plan to use the C++ interface you must look into `cv::Mat`.

Anyway, retrieving frames from the camera and keeping them in memory for later usage requires you to have a buffering mechanism to store the frames. I suggest you look into **circular buffers** (a.k.a. *ringbuffers*) and see how they work:

- [C + OpenCV: IplImage with circular buffer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9733005/176769)
- [Thread safe implementation of circular buffer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9743605/thread-safe-implementation-of-circular-buffer)
- [How to implement a circular buffer of cv::Mat objects (OpenCV)?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9472880/176769)

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I read this post and the code runs, and processes the video. I tried to use it in wince project, but it (cvCaptureFromCAM) doesn't do anything. Do you have any tip for wince?

Comment: Is there any application on your WinCE that can successfully display frames from the camera?

Comment: Yes, there is. The application made of some code found in wince builder. I found out that it uses directshow - that's the reason I don't know how to get to buffers. I read a lot of directshow but I don't know if there is a way to read data from the "transformer filter" (or, how to do it).

Comment: Have you seen [DirectShow with OpenCV](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/DirectShow)?

Comment: Yes, I checked it out but no answer was found. I looked for information about it a lot but no success.